# Ubuntu Java -jar error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, linux, jar, manifest

I develop a simple java program, it only has one main class as follow:

```
public class HelloTest {

  public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@ Hello World! From HelloTest!! ");
  }
}
```

And i use maven assembly plugin to package this program as a runnable jar, the jar package structure as follow:

Test3-0.0.1-assembly.jar

```
|-----META-INF
|         |
|         |---MANIFEST.MF
|
|-----Test3-0.0.1.jar
```

### And this is the manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_18
Class-Path: Test3-0.0.1.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven
Main-Class: com.example.HelloTest
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

After run 'mvn clean packge', maven generates the assembly jar in the target directory, but **the assembly jar's manifest file miss 'Class-Path' field**, so i have to add 'Class-Path' by hand with winrar. I don't know whether it's the maven assembly plugin bug...

Finally, i use 'java -jar Test3-0.0.1-assembly.jar' in windows, it works ok.
But i copy the jar to linux(ubuntu), use the same command 'java -jar Test3-0.0.1-assembly.jar', **it shows error: Could not find or load main class com.example.HelloTest**.

I really don't know why it appears so different in the two system, just the same jar. Could anyone can tell how to solve the problem(make the jar can be run in linux)? Thanks.

Comment: have u changed the permission of jar for execution?

Comment: Could you please post the configuration of the assembly-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I use `maven-jar-plugin` for `MANIFEST` generation. This is my configuration, maybe this will help:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.example.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, i tried maven jar plugin, but its runnable jar only contains program original class file. My demand is that i want to package a runnable jar within all dependency jar package into it. So i choose to use maven assembly plugin, the generated runnable jar can be run in windows, but show errors in ubuntu.

Comment: Hmmm, so this is maybe something with permissons like Juned Ahsan said.